# Is this definition of boundedness correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, bounded-variation

Hi I'm trying to learn precalc and one thing I'm stumped on is the concept of boundedness. From what I understand boundedness is whether or not a function has an absolute maximum and minimum. If it has only max then it is bounded above, otherwise if it has only a minimum it is bounded below. If it is both then its bounded, if it has neither it is not bounded. Is this definition correct? I'm trying to use this logic to check if $y=\sqrt{13-x^2}$ is bounded in any way or not.

Comment: I would say $y=\arctan x$ is bounded, though it doesn't have a maximum or minimum, but $0\le \sqrt{13-x^2}\le \sqrt{13}$

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea, but a function bounded above need not have an absolute maximum, a function bounded below need not have an absolute minimum, and a bounded function need not have either. A real-valued function on $\Bbb R$ is bounded above if there is some real number $m_a$ such that $f(x)\le m_a$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, and it is bounded below if there is some real number $m_b$ such that $f(x)\ge m_b$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. It is bounded if it is bounded both above and below. There is no requirement that $f(x)=m_a$ for some $x$, even if $m_a$ is the smallest real number $m$ with the property that $f(x)\le m$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, and a similar statement is true of $m_b$.

An example of a bounded function that does not have an absolute maximum or minimum is the function $f(x)=\tan^{-1}x$: $-\frac{\pi}2<f(x)<\frac{\pi}2$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, but $f(x)$ has neither an absolute maximum nor an absolute minimum.

Comment: I see. So if there is a absolute max or min it is definitely a bounded function, and the same applies if it contains vertical asymptotes? Also I'm pretty bad at trig, so I'm assuming the inverse tangent has vertical asymptotes from its graph and your description of it.

Comment: @ChrisGeorge: Your first statement is correct, but if it has a *vertical* asymptote, it’s definitely not bounded; did you mean a *horizontal* asymptote? In that case it might or might not be bounded, depending on what it does in the other direction.

Comment: oops sorry, yes I meant horizontal asymptotes. So if there are two horizontal asymptotes it is definitely bounded, right?

Comment: @ChrisGeorge: Only if it approaches the higher one from below and the lower one from above. For a counterexample consider the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1x,&\text{if }x\ne 0\\0,&\text{if }x=0\,.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer(s)!

Comment: @ChrisGeorge: You’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That's not the right condition. If I take the function you gave and multiply it by $1-\sqrt x$, it would now approach the asymptote from below. A better condition is that it's continuous.

Comment: @Acccumulation: *Only* was of course an overstatement, but I was addressing what I suspected was the likeliest confusion, namely, that a horizontal asymptote would **be** a bound. Continuity isn’t required either, and I definitely don’t want to reinforce the common beginner’s tendency to forget about functions that aren’t continuous.

Answer (score 2):

More simply, the "maximum" of a set of numbers is the largest number **in** the set and the "minimum" is the smallest number **in** the set.

The "open interval", (0, 1), the set of all numbers x, 0< x< 1, has 1, and every number larger than 1, as "upper bound" and 1 is the "least upper bound" but is NOT the "maximum" because 1 is not itself in the set.  Similarly, any number 0 or less  is a  "lower bound".  0 is the "greatest lower bound" but is not the "minimum" because it is not itself in the set.

Answer (score 1):

Boundedness does not implies that the function has an absolute maximum or an absolute minimum.

Let consider for example $f(x)=\frac1x$ for $x>0$ which is bounded below but there is not a minimum (there exists an infimum that is zero).

What is true is that when an absolute maximum [or minimum] exists then $f(x)$ is bounded above [or below].